# Avoid nasty warning C4100 in visual-studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

I'm using visual studio 2013 and get a lot of C4100 warnings in cases like this

```
void destroy(pointer p) {//warning C4100
     p->~T(); 
}
```

i don't understand why. My question how can i avoid this warning without #pragma warning (platform-independence, readability)?

Comment: One step back...why do you explicitly call object destructor? There are really few situations where it's useful (and even less situations where it's good). You may _try_ to simply `p;` to _reference_ that parameter without actually doing anything.

Comment: Why not just call `delete p;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio [bug/limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/26kb9fy0.aspx).

> C4100 can also be issued when code calls a **destructor** on a otherwise unreferenced parameter of primitive type. **This is a limitation of the Visual C++ compiler.**

There should a be bug report, but I cant find it at the moment.

**Workarounds:**

1. Reference `p` otherwise:

   ```
   void destroy(pointer p) {
       p;         //resolve warning C4100
       p->~T(); 
   }
   ```
2. Disable the warning:

   - compile without `/W4` or
   - compile with `/wd4100` or
   - add `#pragma warning(disable : 4100)`
3. Use another compiler.